# R - Plotting Hexagon Tessellations

Tags: r, plot, hexagonal-tiles, spatstat, tesselation

I'd like to generate some square plots that have arrays of hexagons inside of them, like drawn [here](http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/tess/bighex.htm).  I'd like to plot both regular (geometrically regular) and abnormal hexagon tessellations, so I don't think tools from the "sp" package will work.

Below is my attempt at a regular hexagon tesselation using owin and plot.

---

```
library(maptools)
library(spatstat)

twid <- 20
theight <-  20
sideL <- 2
rp1 <- (sideL/2)*sqrt(3)
rp2 <- 2*(sideL/2)*sqrt(3)
rp3 <- 3*sideL

    bx <- c(1:floor(twid/rp3))
    by <- c(1:floor(theight/rp3))
    hex_array1 <- list(bx)
    hex_array2 <- list(by)

    for(i in 1:ceiling(twid/rp3)){
        bx[i] <- list(x=c(0+rp3*i,1+rp3*i,3+rp3*i,4+rp3*i,3+rp3*i,1+rp3*i)) 
        by[i] <- list(y=c(rp1,rp2,rp2,rp1,0,0))
            hex_array1[i] <- bx[i]
            hex_array2[i] <- by[i]
    }

    har1 <- list(x=c(0,1,3,4,3,1), y=c(rp1,rp2,rp2,rp1,0,0))

    har2 <- list(x=hex_array1,y=hex_array2)


hexig <- owin(poly=list(list(x=c(0,twid,twid,0), y=c(0,0,theight,theight)),
                        har1, har2
                        )
                )
    plot(hexig)
```

However, the above seems to error out because har2 isn't formatted as a list of lists correctly.

The above is obviously only for a single row of hexagons but I figured once I got the first row I'd just wrap the single row in a for loop that added a set x and y distances for each row. I just can't figure out how to format har2 so that I can directly plug it into owin's poly function.

I'm open to completely changing the way I've done the above, I'm still relatively new to R so I definitely still don't know how to do things the most efficient/elegant way. I'm currently running R version 3.3.2 on Win 10 x64 running RStudio V0.99.903

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly the [dggridR](https://github.com/r-barnes/dggridR/) package could also help.
"dggridR builds discrete global grids which partition the surface of the Earth into hexagonal, triangular, or diamond cells, all of which have the same size."

Comment: I know this is an older post, but the link up top is broken so your example no longer works. Do you have an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `spatstat` has just the functions you are looking for: `hextess`
and `affine.tess`.

Take a look at the examples for `affine.tess`. Here
is an example of what you can do (add `trim = FALSE` to avoid the
bounding box):

```
library(spatstat)
H <- hextess(square(5), 0.2)
plot(H)
```

[image]

```
shear <- matrix(c(1,0,0.6,1), 2, 2)
sH <- affine(H, shear)
plot(sH)
```

[image]

Comment: Compared with my ggplot hack, this directly creates the desired tesselation pattern and is much more flexible in terms of transformations. Hopefully, the OP will return and select this as the best answer. Also, it would be helpful if you got rid of all the `#>` and `#> affn.t>` and just provided the bare code so that people can copy and paste without having to edit out the cursor characters.

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback @eipi10. I have updated my answer to make it easier to copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to just do a hexbin plot and then override the coloring (not that it wouldn't be an interesting programming exercise to plot the hexagon tesselation lines directly). For example, using ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat = data.frame(x=runif(5000, 0,10), y=runif(5000,0,10))

# Basic plot
p = ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_hex(colour="black", fill="white", bins=10) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.4,10.6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0.4,10.6)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank())

# Regular hexagons
p + coord_equal(ratio=1)

# 2:1 aspect ratio
p + coord_equal(ratio=2)
```

`geom_hex` only works with Cartesian coordinates, so this method can only produce hexagons with varying aspect ratios, but not shears or other distortions.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. This is exactly what I was hoping for. Do you know of a way to easily tessellate other combinations of shapes. For example, tesselate squares, hexagons and triangles together? I'm thinking of something like what you can see at the below link. http://www.principlesofnature.com/references/semiregular_tessellations_of_the_plane.htm.

Answer (score 0):

### scale = 1

[image]

### scale = 2

[image]

I wrote a `hexagon()` function that is a base `graphics::polygon()` approach.  Just had to figure out a little bit of the geometry of hexagons and map it to an indexing that made sense.  This is what I came up with:

- The `index_i = 1, index_j=1` hexagon is the lower left hexagon.  It has its leftmost vertex at cartesian coordinate (0,`opp`).  It will be flush on the y=0 line (x-axis).
- The `index_i = 2, index_j=1` hexagon will be adjacent to the right from the `index_i = 1, index_j=1` hexagon (lower left).  It'll be slightly elevated.
- The `index_i=1, index_j=2` will be right on top of the `index_i = 1, index_j=1` hexagon (lower left).
- In this way incrementing `index_i` references hexagons to the right (think of `index_i` as the x-coordinate position) and incrementing `index_j` references hexagons above (think of `index_j` as the y-coordinate position).
- `scale` makes them bigger or smaller
- pass colors to each hexagon with `fill_color`
- Use a double for-loop to tessellate

```
library(RColorBrewer)
mypalette<-brewer.pal(5,"PuOr")[c(-1,-3)]
lwd.in<-1

hexagon<-function(index_i=1, index_j=1, scale=1, fill_color=sample(rev(mypalette)[2],1)){
  
  opp=tan(pi/3)*scale; 
  adj=1*scale;

  side_length <- sqrt(adj^2+opp^2)

vertex_a <- c(  0                ,   opp)
vertex_b <- c(adj                , 2*opp)
vertex_c <- c(adj+side_length    , 2*opp)
vertex_d <- c(adj+adj+side_length,   opp)
vertex_e <- c(  adj+side_length  , 0)
vertex_f <- c(adj                , 0)

cpoint <- c(adj+0.5*side_length,opp)


if( index_i %% 2 == 1){
  
  odds_up_to_index_i <- seq(1,index_i,by=2)
  
  key <- data.frame(      i = seq(from=0, by=3, length.out = length(odds_up_to_index_i)),
                    index_i = odds_up_to_index_i)
  
  i <- key$i[key$index_i == index_i]
  j <- 2*(index_j - 1)
  
  return_hex <-
    polygon(x = c(vertex_a[1],vertex_b[1],vertex_c[1],vertex_d[1],vertex_e[1],vertex_f[1]) + cpoint[1]*i,
            y = c(vertex_a[2],vertex_b[2],vertex_c[2],vertex_d[2],vertex_e[2],vertex_f[2]) + cpoint[2]*j,
            col=fill_color,
            lwd=lwd.in,
            border=sample(c("white","black")[1],1)
            
            
    )
}

if( index_i %% 2 == 0){
  
  i <- index_i - 1
  j <- 2*(index_j - 1)
  
  return_hex <-
    polygon(x = c(vertex_a[1],vertex_b[1],vertex_c[1],vertex_d[1],vertex_e[1],vertex_f[1]) + (cpoint[1]+0.5*side_length)*(i),
            y = c(vertex_a[2],vertex_b[2],vertex_c[2],vertex_d[2],vertex_e[2],vertex_f[2]) + cpoint[2]*(j+1),
            col=fill_color,
            lwd=lwd.in,
            border=sample(c("white","black")[1],1)
    )
  }
}

par(pty="s", mai=c(0,0,0,0)+0.1)
plot(NA,NA,xlim=c(0,200),ylim=c(0,200), axes = FALSE, xlab="", ylab="") ## if you adjust `opp` and `adj` from (7,4)
#box()
abline(v=0)
abline(h=0)

for(i in 1:100){
  for(j in 1:100){
    hexagon(index_i = i, index_j = j)
  }
}

hexagon(index_i = 1, index_j = 1)
hexagon(index_i = 1, index_j = 2)
hexagon(index_i = 1, index_j = 3)
hexagon(index_i = 1, index_j = 4)
hexagon(index_i = 1, index_j = 5)

hexagon(index_i = 2, index_j = 1)
hexagon(index_i = 2, index_j = 2)
hexagon(index_i = 2, index_j = 3)
hexagon(index_i = 2, index_j = 4)
hexagon(index_i = 2, index_j = 5)

hexagon(index_i = 3, index_j = 1)
hexagon(index_i = 3, index_j = 2)
hexagon(index_i = 3, index_j = 3)
hexagon(index_i = 3, index_j = 4)
hexagon(index_i = 3, index_j = 5)

hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 1)
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 2)
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 3)
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 4)
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 5)

hexagon(index_i = 5, index_j = 1)
hexagon(index_i = 5, index_j = 5)
hexagon(index_i = 6, index_j = 1)
hexagon(index_i = 6, index_j = 4)
hexagon(index_i = 7, index_j = 2)
hexagon(index_i = 7, index_j = 3)
hexagon(index_i = 7, index_j = 4)

## Infected: color, white border
hexagon(index_i = 5, index_j = 3, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[3])
## Vaccinated:  deeper color, black border (nah, just white)
hexagon(index_i = 5, index_j = 2, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 6, index_j = 3, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 6, index_j = 2, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 5, index_j = 4, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 2, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 3, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])



## Infected: color, white border
hexagon(index_i = 20, index_j = 20, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[3])
## Vaccinated:  deeper color, black border (nah, just white)
hexagon(index_i = 20, index_j = 19, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 20, index_j = 21, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])

hexagon(index_i = 19, index_j = 20, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 19, index_j = 21, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])

hexagon(index_i = 21, index_j = 20, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 21, index_j = 21, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])



par(pty="s", mai=c(0,0,0,0)+0.1)
plot(NA,NA,xlim=c(0,200),ylim=c(0,200), axes = FALSE, xlab="", ylab="") ## if you adjust `opp` and `adj` from (7,4)
#box()
abline(v=0)
abline(h=0)

scale.in <- 2

for(i in 1:100){
  for(j in 1:100){
    hexagon(index_i = i, index_j = j, scale=scale.in)
  }
}

hexagon(index_i = 1, index_j = 1, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 1, index_j = 2, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 1, index_j = 3, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 1, index_j = 4, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 1, index_j = 5, scale=scale.in)

hexagon(index_i = 2, index_j = 1, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 2, index_j = 2, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 2, index_j = 3, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 2, index_j = 4, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 2, index_j = 5, scale=scale.in)

hexagon(index_i = 3, index_j = 1, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 3, index_j = 2, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 3, index_j = 3, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 3, index_j = 4, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 3, index_j = 5, scale=scale.in)

hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 1, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 2, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 3, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 4, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 5, scale=scale.in)

hexagon(index_i = 5, index_j = 1, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 5, index_j = 5, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 6, index_j = 1, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 6, index_j = 4, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 7, index_j = 2, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 7, index_j = 3, scale=scale.in)
hexagon(index_i = 7, index_j = 4, scale=scale.in)

## Infected: color, white border
hexagon(index_i = 5, index_j = 3, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[3])
## Vaccinated:  deeper color, black border (nah, just white)
hexagon(index_i = 5, index_j = 2, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 6, index_j = 3, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 6, index_j = 2, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 5, index_j = 4, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 2, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 4, index_j = 3, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])



## Infected: color, white border
hexagon(index_i = 20, index_j = 20, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[3])
## Vaccinated:  deeper color, black border (nah, just white)
hexagon(index_i = 20, index_j = 19, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 20, index_j = 21, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])

hexagon(index_i = 19, index_j = 20, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 19, index_j = 21, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])

hexagon(index_i = 21, index_j = 20, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
hexagon(index_i = 21, index_j = 21, scale=scale.in, fill_color=rev(mypalette)[1])
```

Comment: Any idea this can be extended to triangles (not hexagons) with the boundary be a regular hexagon and not a square.